# Retry after Delay for scheduled task in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, timer, combine, ios16

I want to schedule API in certain interval of time, and if that API fails I want to retry that api after certain time and if it hits max retry it should stop calling API, but if it is success it has to continue in scheduled time.

Idea:

- two streams, Timer and dataTaskPublisher.
- Timer will drive the dataTaskPublisher.
- if dataTaskPublisher fails:
- reschdeule timer with some delay()
- if maxretry count reached stop timer(which will stop dataTaskPublisher)

I am kinda lost to orchestrate two streams, Any suggestions for sample would be very helpful.
Apologies for my beginner tryout.

```
var cancellables: AnyCancellable
let interval = 2
let maxRetry = 2
let delay = 5


var timer = Timer.publish(every: TimeInterval(interval), on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
var session =  URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://google.com")!).map(\.data).eraseToAnyPublisher()

cancellables = timer.flatMap{ _ in
    return session.catch { _ -> AnyPublisher<Data, URLError> in 
        return Publishers.Delay(upstream: session,
                                interval: .seconds(delay), tolerance: 1,
                                scheduler: RunLoop.main).print("retrying").retry(maxRetry).eraseToAnyPublisher() 
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}.sink(receiveCompletion: { comp in
        if case let .failure(err) = comp {
            print("=============================This is error \(err)")
            // This doesn't trigger.  


        }
    }, receiveValue: { data in
        print("success")
        
       
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was close to succeeding.

After adding error handling in the dataTaskPublisher using tryMap, we can
use a Fail publisher to propagate the error into the receiveCompletion. So now

- The timer drives the dataTaskPublisher.
- If the dataTaskPublisher fails, we retry it with a delay.
- The session completes with an error if the retries go above maxRetry.

I added a retry_count variable to verify that the number of expected retries does not get exceeded. Please find a new implementation based on your code below.

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

var cancellables: AnyCancellable

var timer = Deferred { Just(Date()) }.append(Timer.publish(every: TimeInterval(interval), on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect())
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let server = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
let interval = 2
let maxRetry = 2
let delay = 5
var retry_count = 0

var session = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: server)!)
    .tryMap { element -> Result<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> in
        print("retry count \(retry_count)")
        if retry_count > maxRetry + 1 {
            print("max retries exceeded")
        }
        guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              httpResponse.statusCode == 200
        else {
            retry_count += 1
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return .success(element)
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()

cancellables = timer.flatMap { _ in
        return session
            .catch { (err: Error) -> AnyPublisher<Result<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error>, Error> in
                return Fail(error: err)
                    .delay(for: .seconds(delay), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
    }
    .retry(maxRetry)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { comp in
        if case let .failure(err) = comp {
            print("=============================This is error \(err)")
            // This now triggers.
        }
    }, receiveValue: { resp in
        retry_count = 0
        print("success")
    })
```

We can test the answer against the following Flask server:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def my_endpoint():
    rnd = random.randint(0, 2)
    if rnd == 0:
        return "not found", 400
    else:
        return "success"

# Run with $ flask --app main.py run
```